# Disabled Cache for Static Content

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, caching, web-config, sitecore

I'm developing a Sitecore site on a local Windows 10 machine. I've try a couple of methods to disable caching CSS, but even in incognito the site shows cached styles.

**Method 1**: Web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <add name="X-ETF-Spoofed-IP" value="xx.xx.xxx.xxx" />
      <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
<staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
</staticContent>
```

**Method 2**: in IIS:
Set Common Headers as Expiring Immediately.

Could there be something missing? The stylesheets are being bundled.

There is this code in Index.cshtml that I didn't write:

```
if (pageItem.TemplateID == Templates.GenericPageTemplateId || pageItem.TemplateID == Templates.GenericMicrositeTemplateId)
{
    headerCss = "generic-header";
}
```

Using Visual Studio.

Comment: Please, validate if this piece of code is part of a "render".  Maybe this render has some cache property enabled.  In that case, the cache is handled by sitecore.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Gabriel mentioned, there are some cache settings based on how you render the contents having CSS stuff. As you said that you want to disable CSS cache and it means you updated CSS file linking to the page. We also have many Sitecore front-end developers and they have similar issue you are facing.

Have you refreshed the page by checking "Disable cache" (Network tab) in Developer Tool?

[image]

If you refresh the page with opening Developer Tool, the page renders without any stored cache information. There is another setting to disable HTML Cache in its web.config file, but I guess the issue is not from there.